# What is the significance of "6,741", the title of an upcoming episode in the fifth season of Person of Interest?

Tags: title, person-of-interest

According to [this Wikia article](http://personofinterest.wikia.com/wiki/Shot_Seeker) **Jonathan Nolan** and **Greg Plageman** mentioned that their favouite episode of *Person of Interest* is the upcoming season 5's 4th episode named **"6,741"**. Is there any hidden meaning behind this title?

Comment: I'm not sure we're supposed to know that yet, so we'll probably just have to guess.

Comment: Is it the fourth? I've seen mentions that this is the title of the seventh episode.

Comment: It's Epidode 7.  [Here's a discussion](http://www.nolanfans.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=22&p=977718) about potential meanings.  I guess we won't know for sure until it airs.

Answer (score 8):

It's the number of different simulations run by Samaritan assets on Sameen Shaw.  The purpose is not explicitly defined, but from context within the episode it seems that:

> She is being run through the same scenario multiple times, after changes/updates are made to a chip inserted behind her ear.  As one operative says to Greer in the room where Shaw is held "This time it took a whole extra hour for her to shoot you in the head", it can be inferred that the purpose of these scenarios is to achieve  a chip capable of controlling Shaw to the extent that she can be used as a Samaritan asset to find/betray the Machine, Finch, Reese and Root.

However, that's just my interpretation - I'm sure the storyline will develop further in future episodes to confirm or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It is the number of simulation that Sameen is subjected to by samaritan operatives to extract information about Team Machine and its latest base of operations.

Comment: Could you flesh this out a little?

Answer (score 0):

The number of simulations Samaritan runs on Shaw trying to compromise her and turn her into a Samaritan operative after rendering her paralysed in a quasi-vegetative state. By inserting a chip to her ear (similar to a cochlear implant in Root's ear), they try to feed her the same scenario multiple times hoping to revive her memories and extract the location of Team Machine and its members.

Answer (score -5):

Episode 4 was filmed after episode 6 to give Sarah Shahi more time to recover from giving birth to twins. If the number 6,742 represents days, it refers to 18 years. If it represents hours, it's 280 days. Is that how long Shaw has been in captivity? After all, 280 days is NINE MONTHS. Yup. I'm going with the hunch that 6,741 refers to the number of hours Shaw has been in captivity, coinciding with her real-life maternity leave. Twins!

Cheesy, but fun.